# Symfony2 get search via forms and links

Tags: forms, search, parameters, symfony, get

In Symfony 2 I tried to create a little search engine. The search consists of a form and some links (like facets on solr). I managed to set up the search form with form binding, creating special searchobject class in entitiess and all this via form post request. For purpose of saving previous searches I saved the complete search object in session serialized.

My question(s) would be:

How to use get requests with a form without outputting form name? Is using forms via get valid in Symfony 2? What is the best practice?

Many sites made with Symfony 2 I see are using www.url.com/search?q=thequery&param2=xxx.

If it's valid, how would I prefill the form? Are there some examples to look at?

(PS: if using the form the way it works now, the url stays the same eg. www.url.com/seach)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change you html form declaration to specify `method="GET"`.

And that's all, you can create your form as usual. :)

Comment: When I do that the url gets really ugly. For instance the form name is ABC, the url becomes www.url.com?ABC[username]="username"... only the braces are url_encoded of course...how to get a clean url.com?param1=xxx&param2=yyy...?

Comment: You can send your data in POST to a specific action which write a sexier url and redirect to another action.